# Running Java Code as a Java Application and not an Applet

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I'm new to Java and I've been trying to run this code as a Java Application instead of a Java applet and it doesn't work (using Eclipse IDE). When I click run, it doesn't give me the option to run it as a Java Application. How would I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import acm.graphics.GOval;
import acm.graphics.GPoint;
import acm.graphics.GRect;
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;

public class Coordinates extends GraphicsProgram {
    public void run() {
        GOval myOval = new GOval(-8, -8, 16, 16);
        myOval.setColor(Color.RED);
        myOval.setFilled(true);
        add(myOval);

    }

}
```

Here are the options given to me when I click run:

[Java_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu3gJ.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: `GraphicsProgram`'s code would be useful

Comment: An applet runs in the web browser plugin. Are you positive it's running as an applet?

Comment: You might have created your project incorrectly in your IDE. Replace the ide tag with eclipse

Comment: Don't use `acm.*`

Comment: This is a subclass of a special api. [This is it](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html)

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere If you look at the image I attached you can see that it gives me no other option but to run it as an applet

Comment: @Alex.G So, in all reality, `GraphicsProgram` is a descent of `Applet`

Comment: No idea, I never figured out how to use eclipse. I use IntelliJ IDEA. It lets you create various run profiles for your project so you can run it in different ways.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I really wouldn't know, this is a code given by my professor and he was very adamant about us running it as a Java Application, but that option doesn't show up for me

Answer (score 2):

The bad news begins with the fact that an ACM based [`GraphicsProgram`](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/complete/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html) extends `Applet`/`JApplet`.

[image]

That's bad news because the Java Plug-In technology needed to run applets and web-start apps was deprecated around Java 9 & removed from the Java API.

---

To do custom painting as suggested in the example, I'd extend a Swing-based `JPanel` and change the paint method, then display it in a `JFrame`.

Anything ACM based is no longer functional.

Answer (score 1):

This is just guess work, as we don't have access to `acm.*` and applets have their defined life cycle, but the intention would be to create a `JFrame` and add the `Coordinates` component to it

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates();
                coordinates.init();
                frame.add(coordinates);
                coordinates.start();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Coordinates extends GraphicsProgram {

        public void run() {
            GOval myOval = new GOval(-8, -8, 16, 16);
            myOval.setColor(Color.RED);
            myOval.setFilled(true);
            add(myOval);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a main method, yo.

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that as well but it gave me an error saying: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method add(GObject) from the type GraphicsProgram

Comment: That means it's working and running your code, but your code has an error in it. 

`add` is an instance method. It requires an instance (object) of the GraphicsProgram class to be invoked. Static methods, in contrast, can be invoked without creating an instance object of their class.

Comment: Well it is a compilation error, not a runtime one, but that makes sense considering the code you've written.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Coordinates());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what `acm` gives you but the answer probably lies between what I posted and the fuller example below

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run it in [Applet Runner for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/applet-runner-eclipse) plug-in. It's a free plug-in to run applets in the IDE.

Full disclosure, I'm the developer of the plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but hope it's useful for others with the same problem.
I ran into the same issue if I click run for individual program in the project. But when I right-click the project (see pic), I can choose Java Application and then pick the specific program to run (I have lots of programs within the project) and then it runs as usual...
Hope this helps with your case. [Java Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKwNu.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).